# Is it possible to use two DC-DC boost converters in series from separate DC sources?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost, series

I was wondering if I could put two DC-DC boost converters in series.

Each of these converters is fed from a DC source which is basically a USB charger of 230VAC to 5VDC/1A.

The voltage output of these converters should have some fixed ratio (i.e. 2.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your title say series but your text body describes a parallel arrangement. Please draw a block diagram of what you are proposing.

Comment: Picture added as requested. I'd add that I am using two *MT3608 boost converters*

Comment: Oh! Now it’s clear. Add a bypass diode across each and you should be good to go as long as the DC input sources are floating towards each other.

Comment: That’s correct on the diodes. You should be good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. As long as the 5Vdc supply is electrically isolated from the mains and the dc supplies do not share a common ground, this should work without a problem.

Comment: So I can do that without bypass diodes as recommended by @winny

Comment: You only really need a bypass diode in parallel with each capacitor if one of the boost converters fails. Then the bypass diode will activate under this fault condition. Keep in mind that in your picture, the connection of the bypass diode is incorrect. You need two diodes if you want to have this optional protection.

Comment: I updated the figure to include your recommendation. I suppose that the added bypass diodes have the same electrical requirements as for the converters' diodes (current handling, reverse voltage blocking and switching speed). Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: Boost or 5 V goes into OCP or similar. Cheap protection against that edge case.